# Unable to read the screen contents via Appium

Tags: appium

I am making an Android app in which there is a screen which has some text contents, and my requirement is to read those contents.

I am using the following code for this:

```
AndroidElement textView = (AndroidElement) driver_and.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.View[@resource-id='__xmlview2--progressLabel']"));

String value=textView.getText();
```

But it is not working.

**EDIT:**

I want to read the Status (Not synced) from the screen. Here is the screenshot taken from the UIAutomator View:

[image: UIAutomator View]

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: I am not getting the desired text

Comment: But what do u get instead of desired text?

Comment: Share the screenshot of inspector

Comment: @Gaurav: I have shared the screenshot for your reference purpose. Kindly check and suggest please.

Comment: hey Gaurav, any updates please....

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
public void dataNotSynced(){
   if(isElementPresent("Not synced")){
     //do something
   }else{
     //don't do anything
   }
}

 public boolean isElementPresent(String locator) {
        try {
            driver.findElementByName(locator);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Sayom.. Does it work? Just curious u didn't pick as the best answer